# yii2 cookies set in localhost but not in live server

Tags: cookies, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have code for setting cookies which works well in localhost but not when I transfer it to the server. What additional setting is needed?

```
public function setLangCookie()
{
    if(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('lang')) {
        Yii::$app->language = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('lang');
    }else
    {
        $cookie = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
        $cookie = new yii\web\Cookie([
          'name'=>'lang',
          'value'=>'en',          
        ]);

      Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some expire time would be nice otherwise cookie lasts until browser is closed:

```
'expire' => time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
```

If you need to send cookie over https you can add this optionally:

```
'secure' => true,
```